# export file in csv.gz format in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, export-to-csv, cassandra-3.0, cqlsh

How to export data from cassandra db to csv.gz file without using stdout and tool like dsbulk?

Is there any way to export in gzip format like we do in postgres "copy tablename to program 'gzip > /path/to/file.csv.gz'"?

Comment: `copy to` is known for having a lot of problems & bad performance.  That's why tool like DSBulk was created

Answer (score 0):

It's much the same with DSBulk. You just have to pipe the output to gzip.

Here's an example:

```
$ dsbulk unload -k ks_name -t table_name | gzip > export.csv.gz
```

For more info, see [Unloading data examples with DSBulk](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/dsbulk/reference/dsbulkUnload.html). Cheers!

Comment: that's not the best idea, as export will use only one thread. the correct way is to specify `--connector.json.compression gzip`: https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/dsbulk/reference/connectorOptions.html?hl=compression#CommontobothCSVandJSONconnectors

Comment: Thanks, Alex! I forgot about that option. 